# reading characters and integers from text file

Tags: c++

I am unable to read data from a text file. The data is in the following format:

```
Balto 85 83 77 91 76
Mickey 80 90 95 93 48
Minnie 78 81 11 90 73
Doc 92 83 30 69 87
Pluto 85 72 49 75 63
Grumpy 27 31 52 74 83
```

I have to calculate the sum of integers in front of every name. No strings allowed, no arrays! Can somebody help me with this??

code i've tried so far is:

```
int main()
{
    ifstream infile;
    char b;
    int x, i=0, sum=0, j=1;

    infile.open("input.txt");

    if (infile.fail())
    {
        cout<<"Unable To Open Input File, File Not Found!!"<<endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    while (i < 6)
    {

        infile.get(b);

        while (b != ' ')
        {
            cout<<b;
            infile.get(b);
        }

        infile>> x;

        while (j<=5)
        {
            sum = sum + x;
            infile>> x;

            j++;
        }

        cout<<"'s Average is: "<<sum/5<<endl;

        i++;

    }
```

Comment: Where's the code you already tried and didn't work?

Comment: This seems like a homework question.

Comment: And aside from the tag, I wouldn't even know the language you're writing it in...

Comment: its c++, i have edited the question and posted my code there. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So, where it fails, do you get any errors?

Comment: it only reads the 1st line correctly, displays the average but doesn't repeat the same for the next 5 lines.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
while (j<=5) {
   sum = sum + x;
   infile>> x;

   j++;
}
```

After the first line `j` is always 5. So, the loop that gets the numbers and calculates the average simply doesn't start. Just reset the `j` back to 1 after the loop:

```
while (j<=5) {
    sum += x;
    infile >> x;

    j++;
}

cout << "Average is: "<< sum / 5.0f << endl;

i++;
j = 1;
sum = 0;
```

Comment: That was one of the mistakes, another thing i figured out was that sum should also be zero after each iteration of loop. But still the problem hasn't solved!!

Comment: Yes, this is another problem that I didn't notice

Comment: `sum / 5` is an integer division. Try with `5.0`.

Comment: In your code you actually try to read 6 numbers. (1 outside the loop, 5 inside) and sum the first 5, but the last >> fails, preventing any further reads.

Comment: @Bob__ True, he should change the while to `while (j<5)` or remove the external `infile >> x;` and switch first two lines inside the loop